# Unable to convert char[] to stream in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am writing a program in which a method takes char[][] as input and returns char[]. Method is as below -

```
private static char[] getTableFromTwoChits(char[][] inputTwoChits) {
    Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(inputTwoChits).forEach(x -> map.put(x[0], x[1]));
    map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    char[] result = new char[inputTwoChits.length+1]; int index=0;
    char startPoint = inputTwoChits[0][0];
    do {
       result[index] = startPoint;index++;
       startPoint = map.get(startPoint);
    }while(startPoint != inputTwoChits[0][0]);
    result[index] = startPoint;
    return result;
}
```

Main method is as follows -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] inputTwoChits = {{'A','B'},{'C','D'},{'B','C'},{'E','F'},{'F','A'},{'D','E'}};
    char[] outputTwoChits = getTableFromTwoChits(inputTwoChits);
    Arrays.stream(outputTwoChits).forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Line 2 in the method getTableFromTwoChits() is compiling fine, whereas line 3 of main method is not compiling. 
Please explain what is the reason behind such behaviour?

Compilation error is mentioned as below -

```
/CircularTableTwoChits.java:21: error: no suitable method found for stream(char[])
        Arrays.stream(outputTwoChits).forEach(System.out::println);
              ^
    method Arrays.<T#1>stream(T#1[]) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: char
        upper bounds: Object)
    method Arrays.<T#2>stream(T#2[],int,int) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Arrays.stream(int[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; char[] cannot be converted to int[])
    method Arrays.stream(long[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; char[] cannot be converted to long[])
    method Arrays.stream(double[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; char[] cannot be converted to double[])
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>stream(T#1[])
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>stream(T#2[],int,int)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `Character` wrapper class

You are trying to make a stream of `char` which is of type primitive. Try this code with the [wrapper](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) class [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html). You will get the desired output.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. int is primitive as well but you can still call Arrays.stream on it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. You are right we can create stream using array of  int, long and double by arrays.stream which returns IntStream, LongStream and DoubleStream respectively but there is no method in arrays class for char which return a stream of char.

Comment: Character[] will work as Object[] method exists in stream

Answer (score 11):

There are only four stream types, for elements of type `int`, `long`, `double`, and reference types (objects). So, since there is no `char` stream, `Arrays.stream` can’t be applied to a `char[]` array.

The canonical representation of a stream of characters is an `IntStream` and acquiring it without copying or boxing overhead works like

```
CharBuffer.wrap(charArray).chars().forEach(c -> System.out.println((char)c));
```

Since the default interpretation of `int` values is “integer number”, you need to use the lambda expression casting it to `char` to interpret it as “character”.

If you don’t need linebreaks between the characters, you can simply print the entire array in one line via

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(charArray));
```

Comment: This solution worked. However in my case, I replaced char[] with Character[]

Answer (score 8):

You cannot create a `CharStream` with  `Arrays.stream(outputTwoChits)`  as there is no overload in the [**Arrays**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class that takes a `char[]` and returns a `CharStream` (infact there is no `CharStream` at all) and doing `Stream.of(outputTwoChits)` would not provide what you'd expect in this particular case.

However, since you're only doing this for printing purposes you can do something like:

```
Arrays.stream(new String(outputTwoChits).split("")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or construct a `String` object from the `char` array and call the `chars` method on it which should produce an `IntStream` and then project from `int` to `char` prior to printing to the console.

```
new String(outputTwoChits).chars().forEach(c -> System.out.println((char)c));
```

Comment: This is also correct. But a simple approach is to replace char[] with Character[]

Answer (score 5):

In

```
Arrays.stream(inputTwoChits)
```

you are passing a `char[][]` array to `<T> Stream<T> stream(T[] array)`, which is fine, since `char[]` is a reference type.

On the other hand, in

```
Arrays.stream(outputTwoChits)
```

you are passing a `char[]`, and `char` is not a reference type, so it doesn't match the signature of `<T> Stream<T> stream(T[] array)`.

You can produce an `IntStream` from a `char[]` using:

```
new String(outputTwoChits).chars()
```

Comment: This is also a possible solution. But changing the method to return Character[] instead  of char[] also worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the static method [`IntStream.range()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) which can be used as follows to create a Stream of indices and then use them to map the values in the `charArray` to a `Character`-stream:

```
Stream<Character> chars = IntStream.range(0, charArray.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> charArray[i]);
```

The `.mapToObj()` method is used, because we're operating on an `IntStream` and we want to convert the unboxed primitive stream to a boxed reference stream.